# Swift Memory Management in Table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, memory, memory-management, uiscrollview

I have a memory issue here in my table view.

1. My table view contain Image ( The image is loaded/Downloaded from API)
2. I use Alamofire to access API and KingFisher to get the image
3. Here is my issues with Memory:

   - When I scroll to the end of table view, I load the image and my memory is increasing. It's Increasing per Image loaded/Downloaded.

All I wanted for my program is, when I scroll down, the image cache from the lasted table cell is cleaned., but when I scroll up, the image is downloaded again.

Comment: This is a good question if someone can answer it.